# Multiple model inheritance with one concrete and one abstract model in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I wanted to inherit the Grandparent abstract model, parent concert model in the child model. How I'll be able to achieve this in django?
There are conflicts in field name as the abstract model is having audit fields. which is common going to be common in both parent and child class. How do I override or remove the common field coming from the parent model?
Below is the models which showcase what I wanted to achieve.

```
class Audit(models.Model):
   is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
   updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)

   class Meta:
      abstract = True

class User(Audit):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=50, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class UserProfile(User, Audit):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_profile'

    address = models.TextField(null=True)
    profile_image = models.TextField(null=True)
    dob = models.DateField() 
.....
```

Comment: Why do you inherit from `Audit` a second time? It is already sufficient that you do this through the `User` model.

Comment: When I inherit `User` the `Audit` fields are of the `User` model. I'll be needing separate audit fields for `User Profile` model.